# How to create automatic array?

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and would like to create a drop down box which displays every year from xxxx to the present year, I can handle the implementation into the drop down box but would like to know if I can have php automatically create an array with all of these years in to save typing them in manually.

Comment: starting at what year? - because a for loop would suite you perfectly if you know the starting spot

Comment: If you are also new to StackOverflow, please read the [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) especially the `Asking questions` part :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function range (see [the range docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.range.php)) to accomplish this

```
$years = range(2013, 2050);
```

The optional third parameter is the step (standard is 1).

Comment: + for including the example code.

Comment: Bitte, change the link to English language :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't realise I still had the german version of the docs running.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an array:

```
$array_years = range($start_year, $end_year, $steps); //$steps is optional

foreach($array_years AS $years) {

    //output options

}
```

Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php

Alternative: use a `for` loop (see other answers for example code)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use simple `for` loop to generate it.

```
echo "<select>";
for($i = from; $i <= to; $i++){
 echo "<option>" . $i . "</option>;
}
echo "</select>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
<?php
$startYear = "";
$endYear = date("Y");

while($startYear != $endYear){
    echo '<option>'.$startYear.'</option>';
    $startYear++;
}
?>
</select>
```

should do it

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="year">
<?php
$start = 1960;
for($i=$start; $i < date("Y"); $i++) {
    echo '<option>' . $i . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
```